# git merge-base で３個以上のコミットを指定して、 --octopus を指定しない用途があるのか

Tags: git

git merge-base で３個以上コミットを指定すると、２個目以降のコミットがマージされたような、仮想的なマージコミットと、１個目のコミットに対しての merge-base 判定が実行されます。 https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base

この挙動を、実際に利用する場面があるのでしょうか。

というのも、`git merge-base --octopus` を付与すると、指定されたすべてのコミットたちすべてについての best common ancestor が出力されます。 merge-base の用途から考えるとこちらの方が挙動としてシンプルでわかりやすいと考えたのですが、そうではなく、上で記したような動作が(わざわざ)デフォルトになっているのは、何か意味(特定の用途)があるのでしょうか。